# How to get Device(iOS,Android) CPU and Memory using Javascript or at client side

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cpu, ram

How to get Device's (iOS,Android) CPU and Memory using Javascript or at client side.

Answer (score 0):

While there's a lot of iOS and Android devices, it's possible to maintain a database of user agent strings and their mappings to devices, and therefore their CPU and RAM. This won't be 100% perfect but its the best I can think of.

Comment: Thnx Ian,But i need something like when i run .html or .js file ,i want the Device hardware information.it should be at client end.